# Tow definition of function "return" in monad transformer MaybeT

Tags: haskell

MaybeT is defined as

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

And, MaybeT m is also an instance of the Monad class, the function `return` is defined like

```
return  = MaybeT . return . Just
```

But I read that `"It would also have been possible (though arguably less readable) to write return = MaybeT . return . return"`, this confused me.

How does `return = MaybeT . return . return` equals to `return  = MaybeT . return . Just` ?

Comment: `Maybe` is also a monad: `instance Monad Maybe where { return = Just; Just x >>= f = f x; Nothing >>= _ = Nothing }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Haskell functions like `return` are polymorphic. If you examine the type of `return` you'll see that it's `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` which indicates that it works for any monad. As it turns out, `Maybe` is a monad and so there must be (somewhere in the standard libraries) an `instance` declaration like

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  return = ...
  ...
```

and, as it turns out, the instance definition of `return` for `Maybe` is

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  return = Just
```

So that indicates why we are *allowed* to replace `return` with `Just`, but it doesn't explain why Haskell actually does it.

It turns out that Haskell uses type inference to decide what the "actual" type of a polymorphic function is. So, to be clear, what's happening in your example is that Haskell is able to recognize that the rightmost `return` must return a value wrapped in `Maybe` and thus knows to specialize `return` to `return :: a -> Maybe a` and then it uses the `instance Monad Maybe` definition for `return` and turns it into `Just`.

Answer (score 7):

Consider `MaybeT`'s definition:

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

First `return` definition (read it from down to up):

```
return =
  MaybeT .   -- put `m (Maybe a)` into `MaybeT`: MaybeT (m (Maybe a))
    return . -- put `Maybe a` into external monad: m (Maybe a)
      Just   -- put value into `Maybe`: Maybe a
```

`Maybe` is a monad too. It's `return` is a `Just`. That's why second `MaybeT`'s `return` defines exactly the same function:

```
return =
  MaybeT .   -- put `m (Maybe a)` into `MaybeT`: MaybeT (m (Maybe a))
    return . -- put `Maybe a` into external monad: m (Maybe a)
      return -- it's the same as `Just` for `Maybe`: Maybe a
```